# Require username and password to be required when logging into workgroup server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login, credentials

We have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Server as Workgroup server. We have created users. When users log on from another computer on the local network their username and password is saved on that computer. We don't want this. What we want is for the user to be required to enter their username and password whenever they log in to the server from a computer on the local network.

Every time when I access the folder on the server from a network computer it opens easily. The username and password are request the first time but next time it doesn't prompt for any credentials. I want to be prompted for the user name and password every time I access the server's folders.

Comment: Why not use the Server 2008 R2 as a domain controller and add your workstations (pro versions of OS and above) to this domain. You can then centrally manage users and computers. The whole point of access control is those who need/have access are supposed to easily access the data they need...

Comment: @BigChris From the sound of it, they're logging into the workstations with a single, generic account.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this but you should be able to prevent Windows from storing/using saved credentials when accessing network resources as follows. Do this on each workstation where you want to prevent credentials from being stored:

1. Open Credentials Manager
2. In the *Windows Credentials* section delete any saved credentials for your workgroup file server
3. Open Local Group Policy Editor (run `gpedit.msc`)
4. Navigate to `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options`
5. Set to `Enabled` the policy setting **Network Access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication** (renamed to *Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication* in Windows 8 and later)
6. Reboot the workstation

This will prevent the workstation from saving credentials for **all** remote computers, not just the workgroup server.  If you ever remove/disable the policy setting in step #5 above, and credentials that were previously in Credentials Manager will reappear.

Credit to http://windowsitpro.com/en/preventing-users-using-iremember-passwordi-feature

Comment: @Jagjit Did this solution work for you?